# What is the jQuery for setting inner value using the outer attribute?

Tags: jquery

I need to change the value "LOCAL" to "REMOTE" in the html snippet below. Can anyone please advise how it is done?

```
<td headers="COMMENT">
  <input type="text" name="f12" size="60" maxlength="2000" value="Archived" id="f12_0001">
  <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="<input type=&quot;hidden&quot; name=&quot;f13&quot; value=&quot;LOCAL&quot;  />" class="rowHandle" id="f01_0001">
</td>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is that a valid html?

Comment: What you are trying to acheive?

Comment: Yes, the html is quite valid.

Answer (score 0):

correct your html as following

```
<td headers="COMMENT">
    <input type="text" name="f12" size="60" maxlength="2000" value="Archived" id="f12_0001"/>
      <input type="text" name="f01" value="local" class="rowHandle" id="f01_0001"/>
</td>
```

and you can change value of input with jquery by using .val because .val is used for input tag

```
$(function() {

    $('#f01_0001' ).val('Remote');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zW2e2/

Comment: That is to set the outer value not the inner one. Someone gave me this construct to read it and that works fine, $($(selector).val()).val(). I've tried $($(selector).val()).val('Remote') but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is wrong  Roobie... check this                                 var somevalue=$(selector).val();
$('input').val(somevalue).

Comment: If you notice the input tag is nested: <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="<input type=&quot;hidden&quot; name=&quot;f13&quot; value=&quot;LOCAL&quot;  />" class="rowHandle" id="f01_0001">. The second input is the value of the first input. Also the second input has its own value and that what I am trying to modify